# Python segmentation fault in interactive mode

Tags: python, miniconda

The python is installed with conda:

```
(base) [kangl@login05]~% which python
~/miniconda3/bin/python
```

When directly run python in iteractive mode, a segmentation fault will apear:

```
(base) [kangl@login05]~% python
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:08:06) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
zsh: segmentation fault  python
```

However, the python script runs successfully:

```
(base) [kangl@login05]~% python -c "print('hello world')"
hello world
```

And ipython runs successfully:

```
(base) [kangl@login05]~% ipython
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:08:06) [GCC 11.3.0]
Type 'copyright', 'credits' or 'license' for more information
IPython 8.12.0 -- An enhanced Interactive Python. Type '?' for help.

In [1]:
```

Then I try to debug it with gdb:

```
(base) [kangl@login04]~% gdb python
GNU gdb (GDB) 11.2
Copyright (C) 2022 Free Software Foundation, Inc.
License GPLv3+: GNU GPL version 3 or later <http://gnu.org/licenses/gpl.html>
This is free software: you are free to change and redistribute it.
There is NO WARRANTY, to the extent permitted by law.
Type "show copying" and "show warranty" for details.
This GDB was configured as "x86_64-conda-linux-gnu".
Type "show configuration" for configuration details.
For bug reporting instructions, please see:
<https://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/bugs/>.
Find the GDB manual and other documentation resources online at:
    <http://www.gnu.org/software/gdb/documentation/>.

For help, type "help".
Type "apropos word" to search for commands related to "word"...
Reading symbols from python...
(gdb) run
Starting program: /users/kangl/miniconda3/bin/python
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:08:06) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaab96b691 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
```

And

```
(gdb) run
Starting program: /users/kangl/miniconda3/bin/python
[Thread debugging using libthread_db enabled]
Using host libthread_db library "/lib64/libthread_db.so.1".
Python 3.10.10 | packaged by conda-forge | (main, Mar 24 2023, 20:08:06) [GCC 11.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x00002aaaab96b691 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
(gdb) backtrace
#0  0x00002aaaab96b691 in __strlen_sse2_pminub () from /lib64/libc.so.6
#1  0x00002aaaaac53f49 in _rl_init_locale ()
   from /users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/../../libreadline.so.8
#2  0x00002aaaaac54044 in _rl_init_eightbit ()
   from /users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/../../libreadline.so.8
#3  0x00002aaaaac32797 in rl_initialize ()
   from /users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/../../libreadline.so.8
#4  0x00002aaaaaad4a7d in setup_readline (mod_state=0x2aaab21b02a0)
    at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.10/Modules/readline.c:1289
#5  PyInit_readline () at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.10/Modules/readline.c:1502
#6  0x000055555576939a in _PyImport_LoadDynamicModuleWithSpec (fp=0x0,
    spec=<ModuleSpec(name='readline', loader=<ExtensionFileLoader(name='readline', path='/users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so') at remote 0x2aaab21b09a0>, origin='/users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', loader_state=None, submodule_search_locations=None, _set_fileattr=True, _cached=None) at remote 0x2aaab21b02e0>)
    at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.10/Python/importdl.c:167
#7  _imp_create_dynamic_impl (module=<optimized out>, file=<optimized out>,
    spec=<ModuleSpec(name='readline', loader=<ExtensionFileLoader(name='readline', path='/users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so') at remote 0x2aaab21b09a0>, origin='/users/kangl/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so', loader_state=None, submodule_search_locations=None, _set_fileattr=True, _cached=None) at remote 0x2aaab21b02e0>)
    at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.10/Python/import.c:2050
#8  _imp_create_dynamic (module=<optimized out>, args=args@entry=0x2aaab212e998, nargs=<optimized out>)
    at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.10/Python/clinic/import.c.h:330
#9  0x0000555555694d14 in cfunction_vectorcall_FASTCALL (
    func=<built-in method create_dynamic of module object at remote 0x2aaaaab8e610>, args=0x2aaab212e998,
    nargsf=<optimized out>, kwnames=<optimized out>) at /usr/local/src/conda/python-3.10.10/Objects/methodobject.c:430
#10 0x000055555568a39b in do_call_core (kwdict={},
--Type <RET> for more, q to quit, c to continue without paging--
```

It looks the dependency on readline library is broken as [Max](https://stackoverflow.com/users/1442918/max) said. But I have no idea how to fix it. I have tried to reinstall the `readline` with `mamba install -c conda-forge readline --force-reinstall` but it doesn't work.

Comment: My guess is your readline library or similar is broken.  A core dump might help you get a bit of a traceback to pinpoint it.

Comment: Worth rebuilding or upgrading to see if it got patched. This looks like a bug.

Comment: Hi Max, I think you are right. I use gdb to debug it and it looks something is wrong with readline lib. I add the traceback to the question, but I don't know how to interpret it. If you can help I will appreciate it a lot!

Comment: Can you add what version of OSX / what architecture you're using? It may be relevant.

Comment: This seems similar to this [debian bug](https://bugs.debian.org/cgi-bin/bugreport.cgi?bug=1021109), where a non-existant locale crashes readline inside `_rl_init_locale`. Could you run the command `locale` in zsh and post the output?

Comment: It is centos 7 on the HPC of my university. The output of `locale` is
```locale: Cannot set LC_CTYPE to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_MESSAGES to default locale: No such file or directory
locale: Cannot set LC_ALL to default locale: No such file or directory
LANG=C.UTF-8
LC_CTYPE="C.UTF-8"
LC_NUMERIC=en_US.UTF-8
LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8
LC_COLLATE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MONETARY="C.UTF-8"
LC_MESSAGES="C.UTF-8"
LC_PAPER="C.UTF-8"
LC_NAME="C.UTF-8"
LC_ADDRESS="C.UTF-8"
LC_TELEPHONE="C.UTF-8"
LC_MEASUREMENT="C.UTF-8"
LC_IDENTIFICATION="C.UTF-8"
LC_ALL=```

Comment: I think it is something at my end. There is a python in the system works fine: ```(base) [kangl@login02]~% module load python
(base) [kangl@login02]~% which python
/hpc/applications/anaconda/3/bin/python
(base) [kangl@login02]~% python
Python 3.6.7 | packaged by conda-forge | (default, Mar  4 2020, 16:55:12)
[GCC 7.3.0] on linux
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> exit()
(base) [kangl@login02]~%```

Comment: I am also encountering this exact same error. Did you find a resolution to get python (installed via conda) running?

Comment: I too am facing this issue - has anyone resolved it? My crash occurs at:

# trying /home/mrim/my_user/miniconda3/lib/python3.10/lib-dynload/readline.cpython-310-x86_64-linux-gnu.so
Segmentation fault

Comment: please look at @Mathews24's answer which fixes my problem.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

After encountering similar errors, I have found that the following lines of code solve the segmentation fault:

```
export LANGUAGE=UTF-8 
export LC_ALL=en_US.UTF-8 
export LANG=UTF-8 
export LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8
export LANG=en_US.UTF-8 
export LC_COLLATE=$LANG 
export LC_CTYPE=$LANG 
export LC_MESSAGES=$LANG 
export LC_MONETARY=$LANG 
export LC_NUMERIC=$LANG 
export LC_TIME=$LANG 
export LC_ALL=$LANG
```